# React Contexts -The property does not exist in the type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Hello to all I am using contexts and there is a component that gives me the following error:

The property 'rubrosItem1' does not exist in the type '{ user: any; setUser: any; }'.ts(2339)
The property 'rubrosItem2' does not exist in the type '{ user: any; setUser: any; }'.ts(2339)

The problem is that I use that context in many components but only one gives me an error.

This is how you define the contexts of the items

```
import { createContext, useContext } from "react";
import { RubroType1, RubroType2 } from "../Interfaces/interfaces";

export const  RubroContext1 = createContext <Partial<RubroType1>>({})
export const  RubroContext2 = createContext <Partial<RubroType2>>({})
```

And this is how I define the interfaces.

```
import { Dispatch, SetStateAction } from "react"

  export interface userI{
    email:string
    name:string
    last_name:string
  }


  export type UserType = {
    user: userI;
    setUser: Dispatch<SetStateAction<usuario>>;
  }


  export interface itemRubro {
    rubro:string
    description:string
    picture1:string
    picture2:string
    picture3:string
  }

  
  export type RubroType1 = {
    rubrosItem1 : itemRubro;
    setItemRubro1: Dispatch<SetStateAction<itemRubro >>;
  }

  export type RubroType2 = {
    rubrosItem2 : itemRubro;
    setItemRubro2 : Dispatch<SetStateAction<itemRubro >>;
  }
```

But Why compiler says type { user: any; setUser: any; }? Because in the definition of RubroContext1 or RubroContext2 there is not user and setUser types?

Here is the summary definition of the App component

```
const App: React.FC = () => {

    const [user,setUser] = useState <usuario> ({
        email:"",
        name:"",
        last_name:"",
    })

 const [rubrosItem1,setItemRubro1] = useState <itemRubro>({
      rubro:"",
      description:"",
      picture1:"",
      picture2:"",
      picture3:"",
    })
 const [rubrosItem2,setItemRubro2] = useState <itemRubro>({
    rubro:"",
    description:"",
    picture1:"",
    picture2:"",
    picture3:"",
    })

    //......
    return(
        <UserContext.Provider  value={ {user,setUser} } >
        <RubroContext1.Provider  value={ {rubrosItem1,setItemRubro1} } >
            <RubroContext2.Provider  value={ {rubrosItem2,setItemRubro2} } >
                <IonApp>
                    <IonReactRouter>
                        <IonRouterOutlet id="main">
                
                            <Route path="/" render={() => isReg ?   ( cliente ?  <HomeClient setIsReg={setIsReg}  /> :<HomeProvider  setIsReg={setIsReg} /> )  :<Inicio  /> } />
                            
                            <Route path="/home" render={() =>  isReg ? (cliente ?  <HomeClient setIsReg={setIsReg} /> :<HomeProvider  setIsReg={setIsReg} /> ) :<Inicio /> } ></Route>
                            
                            //.......
                                        
                        </IonRouterOutlet>
                    </IonReactRouter>
                </IonApp>
            </RubroContext2.Provider>
        </RubroContext1.Provider>
        </UserContext.Provider >  
  );
};
```

This is the HomeProvider component that gives me this error. It is necessary to mention that HomeClient does not give me the error and the implementation is the same. Since I do the same import and the HomeCliente component is in the same folder as the HomeProvider

```
import { RubroContext1, RubroContext2 } from "../../Contexts/RubroContext";
//...

const HomeProvider = (props:{setIsReg:string}) =>{
  
  const {rubrosItem1,setItemRubro1} = useContext (RubroContext1) 
  const {rubrosItem2,setItemRubro2} = useContext (RubroContext2) 

  if ((rubrosItem1!.rubro!="" && rubrosItem1!.rubro!=undefined) && (rubrosItem2!.rubro!="" && rubrosItem2!.rubro!=undefined)){
      return (
        <div style={{display:"flex", flexDirection:"column", width:"100%",height:"100%", justifyContent:"center", alignItems:"center"}}>
          <IonItem style={{width:"80%"}}  onClick={() => (props.verRubros(rubrosItem1!.rubro))}>
              <strong> {rubrosItem1!.rubro} </strong>
              <img style={{width:"32px", height:"32px"}} src={retornarIconoCategoria(rubrosItem1!.rubro)}></img>

          </IonItem>
          <IonItem style={{width:"80%"}}  onClick={() => (props.verRubros(rubrosItem2!.rubro))}>
              <strong> {rubrosItem2!.rubro} </strong>
              <img style={{width:"32px", height:"32px"}} src={retornarIconoCategoria(rubrosItem2!.rubro)}></img>
          </IonItem>
        </div>
      )
  }else if((rubrosItem1!.rubro=="" || rubrosItem1!.rubro==undefined) && (rubrosItem2!.rubro!="" && rubrosItem2!.rubro!=undefined)){ 
      return (
          <div style={{display:"flex", flexDirection:"column", width:"100%",height:"100%", justifyContent:"center", alignItems:"center"}}>
            <IonItem style={{width:"80%"}}  onClick={() => (props.verRubros(rubrosItem2!.rubro))}>
                  <strong> {rubrosItem2!.rubro} </strong>
                  <img style={{width:"32px", height:"32px"}} src={retornarIconoCategoria(rubrosItem2!.rubro)}></img>
              </IonItem>
              < div style={{display:"flex", width:"100%", flexDirection:"column", justifyContent:"center", alignItems:"center", textAlign:"center"}}>
                <p style={{fontSize:"0.9em", marginTop:"45px"}}> AGREGAR OTRO RUBRO</p>
                <IonButton color="warning" shape="round" style={{width:"40px", height:"40px",}} ><p style={{fontSize:"1.4em", color:"black", fontWeight:"bold"}}>+</p></IonButton>
            </div>
           </div>
      )
  }else if((rubrosItem1!.rubro!="" && rubrosItem1!.rubro!=undefined) && (rubrosItem2!.rubro=="" || rubrosItem2!.rubro==undefined)){ 
      return (
        <div style={{display:"flex", flexDirection:"column", width:"100%",height:"100%", justifyContent:"center", alignItems:"center"}}>
        <IonItem style={{width:"80%"}} onClick={() => (props.verRubros(rubrosItem1!.rubro))}>
                  <strong> {rubrosItem1!.rubro} </strong>
              <img style={{width:"32px", height:"32px"}} src={retornarIconoCategoria(rubrosItem1!.rubro)}></img>
        </IonItem>
        < div style={{display:"flex", width:"100%", flexDirection:"column", justifyContent:"center", alignItems:"center", textAlign:"center"}}>
                    <p style={{fontSize:"0.9em", marginTop:"45px"}}> AGREGAR OTRO RUBRO</p>
                    <IonButton color="warning" shape="round" style={{width:"40px", height:"40px",}} ><p style={{fontSize:"1.4em", color:"black", fontWeight:"bold"}}>+</p></IonButton>
            </div>
</div>
      )
  }else{
      return (
        <div style={{display:"flex", flexDirection:"column", textAlign:"center", width:"100%",height:"100%", justifyContent:"center", alignItems:"center"}}>
          <h1>NO POSEE RUBROS CARGADOS</h1>
          <IonButton shape="round" id="boton-inicialBR" onClick={() => >AGREGAR RUBRO</IonButton>
        </div>
      )
  }

}
```